# Visual studio 2015 Intellitest not working on 64bit projects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, intellitest

I am trying to run intellitest on x64 project (for that matter i even tried to create simple 64x project)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if(args == null)
            throw new Exception("test");
    }
}
```

but for some reason all i get in intellitest output is

```
saving all files
building project
Launching exploration
starting...
preparing monitored process for 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Unitest\ConsoleApplication9\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication9.exe'
failed to prepare process for assembly 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Unitest\ConsoleApplication9\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication9.exe'
monitored process exited with error while loading assembly (-1006 - 0xfffffc12)
finished
```

Comment: Please report this as a bug on MS Connect. The team is responsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the feedback.
This is by design. IntelliTest is not supported for x64 configuration at the moment.

Comment: Really hard to love VS when design decisions like this are made.

Comment: Please consider voting for the feature here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/10139661-enable-intellitest-for-64-bit-projects. We are grateful for your feedback.

Comment: Still not working by design? This is kind of ridiculous that MSFT is forcing my programs into a 32 or 64 bit selection and then not supporting those coercions.

Comment: How is it this guy doesnt really seem to know _anything_ considering his position? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/159390/intellitest-failed-to-prepare-process-for-asssembl.html