# Visual studio 2017 create Intellitest not working

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, intellitest

<sub>**Note: Answering my own problem for future developers.**</sub>

I right click a Method > Create Intelli Tests.

I choose the MSTestv2, chose the Project.Test project, click OK and see the following output:

> Processing Proj.API
>   Scanning assembly references in Proj.API Applying
>   template AssemblyInfo to Proj.API Applying template Tests to Proj.API
>   test stubbing ProductController -> ProductControllerIntelliTest
>   generating method bodies
>   flushing generated code

Unfortunately the Test.cs file is NOT created.

I've [set all projects x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166277/visual-studio-2015-intellitest-not-working-on-64bit-projects) and that doesn't make a difference.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

For some reason I had to specify a New Project for the Intelli Tests.

Creating new IntelliTests in the new project work, however they cant be added to the standard Test Project.

<sub>Hopefully someone else knows why.</sub>